# Como consigo analisar vários elementos distintos no excel usando 3 lógicas para a mesma coluna?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Então pessoal, tenho que arrrumar uma tabela do excel de investimentos, mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso. São 2 lógicas para uma coluna onde aparece a (Diferença de um produto comprado no dia anterior menos o valor dele no exato momento)Vezes o tanto de títulos/produtos comprados ou seja:

```
(P1,2,3,... - D1,2,3,..) * I1,2,3,...
```

Essa no caso é quando tenho apenas que multiplicar pela quantidade de produtos, é a primeira lógica resolvida, a segunda, é ter que analisar os diferentes números na coluna I **("I" é a coluna de quantidades de produtos, que também tem números negativos, que são negativos apenas pelo fato de estarem sendo vendidos, e os positivos por estarem sendo comprados)** e terem que somar os números "soltos" que são os números que não estão "casados" ( ou seja que não se cancelam, por exemplo, um cliente comprou 5000 camisas, mas teve que vender -5000 camisas de outra marca, então se cancelam ) daí por exemplo se tem dois "casais" e dpis "soltos" como: -5000+5000;-3000+3000; 6000 e 3000, gostaria de fazer a fórmula de
(P1,2,3,... - D1,2,3,..) * I1,2,3,... apenas para esses dois "soltos" e somar o resultado deles, alguém bom nessa área pra dar uma ajudinha criativa pra esse problema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Acredito que a formular [SES](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ses-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45?ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR) resolva seu problema.

#### Sintaxe simples

Geralmente, a sintaxe da função SES é:

```
=SES([Algo é verdadeiro1, Valor se verdadeiro1,Algo é verdadeiro2,Valor se verdadeiro2,Algo é verdadeiro3,Valor se verdadeiro3)
```

Observe que a função SES permite testar até 127 condições diferentes. No entanto, não é recomendável aninhar muitas condições com instruções SE ou SES. Isso porque condições múltiplas precisam ser inseridas na ordem correta, o que pode ser difícil de criar, testar e atualizar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Opa show de bola amigo, obrigado pela dica, o que me preocupa mesmo é como vou colocar nessa condição de lógica se por exemplo os números forem iguais, mas opostos, tipo 5000 e -5000, e daí ignorar essas "casadas" e analisar somente as q não estão casadas

Comment: ta meio dificil entender sua pergunta, mas talvez `procv` com `ses` da um caminho, eu ainda não entendi direito, mas da uma pensada com isso

Comment: opa tranquilo amigo, vou mandar uma ft pra ilustrar melhor